# GPS coordinates in degrees to calculate distances

Tags: iphone, ios4, dictionary, gps

On the iPhone, I get the user's location in decimal degrees, for example: latitude 39.470920 and longitude = -0.373192; That's point A.

I need to create a line with another GPS coordinate, also in decimal degrees, point B. Then, calculate the distance (perpendicular) between the line from A to B and another point C.

The problem is I get confused with the values in degrees. I would like to have the result in meters. What's the conversion needed? How will the final formula to compute this look like?

Comment: I also have the same problem, and neither one of the 2 answers here currently solve that. RabinDev's answer got closer, but he didn't solve the degrees to meters conversion problem. Any tips?

Answer (score 29):

Why don't you use [CLLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html)s `distanceFromLocation:` method? It will tell you the precise distance between the receiver and another CLLocation.

```
CLLocation *locationA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:12.123456 longitude:12.123456];
CLLocation *locationB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:21.654321 longitude:21.654321];

CLLocationDistance distanceInMeters = [locationA distanceFromLocation:locationB];

// CLLocation is aka double

[locationA release];
[locationB release];
```

It's as easy as that.

Comment: hi Toastor Distance calculation any sample example send it please

Comment: Done. Things like that are easy to learn from the reference library though. I posted the link in my answer, you may want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location is the method to get the distance from on CLLocation to another.

Your problem is also of finding the shortest line between a line (A,B) and point C.
I guess if your 3 CLLocations are near ( less than a few kilometers apart), you can do the math "as if" the coordinates are points on a single plane, and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment/1501725#1501725) in C++, or [this](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpointdist.html) or [this](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointline/) and just use the CLLocations "as if" they were x and y coordinates on a plane.

If your coordinates are far away, or exact accuracy is important then the spherical shape of the earth matters, and you need to do things using [great circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) and other geometry on the face of a sphere.

Comment: hi rabindev any sample example send it please

Comment: plus1 for the super geeky spherical reference. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0+**

**Only calculate distance between two coordinates:**

```
let distance = source.distance(from: destination)
```

**When you have array of locations:**

To get distance from array of points use below reduce method.

Here `locations` is array of type `CLLocation`.

```
 let calculatedDistance = locations.reduce((0, locations[0])) { ($0.0 + $0.1.distance(from: $1), $1)}.0
```

Here you will get distance in **meters**.