# Calculate distance between two place using latitude-longitude in gmap for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GPS coordinates in degrees to calculate distances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994101/gps-coordinates-in-degrees-to-calculate-distances)

How to Calculate distance between two place using latitude-longitude in gmap for iPhone?
Calculate distance between two place using latitude-longitude in gmap for iPhone

Comment: If you have the latitude and longitude of two points, you can calculate the distance between them using the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Answer (score 266):

You have to **use Core Location Framework**. So don't forget to Add & import Core Location Framework.

#### Objective-C

```
 #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

 CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];

 CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];

 CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];

 //distance in Meters

 //1 meter == 100 centimeter

 //1 meter == 3.280 feet

 //1 square meter == 10.76 square feet


 [locA release];

 [locB release];
```

#### Swift

```
import CoreLocation

let locA = CLLocation(latitude: lat1, longitude: long1)

let locB = CLLocation(latitude: lat2, longitude: long2)

let distance = locA.distance(from: locB)
```

Comment: I have done this and for some reason distance is always zero. I have tried with other coordinates in another continent and it still returns zero.

Comment: What does square feet in this context? Does that make sense?

Comment: Memory Question:  Why do you need a pointer for *locA and *locB but you dont need it for distance?

Comment: jspooner, `CLLocationDistance` is a primitive type (double) so does not use pointers. `CLLocation` is an object, so you need to use pointers.

Comment: "meter" -> "square meter" is not too minor, people, it really alters the meaning of what is said...

Comment: what to do if i have to plot these points on my view based on the diameter of my radar view?

Comment: is there any way to find time spam between two point ???

Comment: @AliRaza try this dude.Someone can find it as helpful.http://www.perspecdev.com/blog/2012/02/22/using-corelocation-on-ios-to-track-a-users-distance-and-speed/

Answer (score 11):

if you have the location parameter, create 2 CLLocations and use `[location1 distanceFromLocation:location2]` method.