# Sort Google places autocomplete results by distance using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm using Google places autocomplete iOS API [(as instructed here)](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete)

I need to sort the results to show the nearest places first.
Can I do this using the iOS API? if yes, please point me to a reference or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to get the user's location, then calculate the distance between each point and the user like this

> [Calculate distance between two place using latitude-longitude in gmap for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175412/calculate-distance-between-two-place-using-latitude-longitude-in-gmap-for-iphone)

then order it by the distance.