# How to obtain, save and calculate distance between coordinates with CoreLocation

Tags: iphone, ios4, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GPS coordinates in degrees to calculate distances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994101/gps-coordinates-in-degrees-to-calculate-distances)

Hi friends I am new iPhone developer.

I am working with the iOS GPS to find the distance between my current location and a previous location.

First of all I don't know how to find my current location. Please tell me.

I have a method that is called to find my current location and previous location. I can only get the current location from CoreLocation  - how can I get hold of my previous location.

I am fully confused please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this basic tutorial on using CoreLocation [iOS Core Location GPS Tutorial](http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/) . It explains in simple terms how to obtain a location, save it and do simple calculations with other locations.

To calculate the distance between to coordinates use the `distanceFromLocation:` method.

Comment: hi Niels Castle thank you so much it is very use full for me.

Comment: hi Niels i am running with core location demo app in device current location is showing successfully but when ever i move location is not updated what is the reason please tell me.

Comment: If u don't mind please tell me distance calculation concept also.

Comment: @Durga I think you respect the answer by accepting it or upvoting it.

Comment: See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905896 for a description of calculating distance between two locations. Follow the steps in the tutorial referenced and take a walk down the street - you should then see the location get updated.