# xcode mapview when scroll, detect nearby points from array of points

Tags: ios, xcode6, mkmapview

First, Thanks in advance :)
I'm working on a native iOS App. I've an array of points (lats&longs) and I need when user scroll in the mapview, Detect the nearby points (points from array) from the current scrolling position.
Are there any tutorials or examples regarding this?

Comment: Iterate over the array and compute the distance to all possible points. If this distance is within a certain limit ('nearby'), then do something with that point.

Comment: Yes this is a good solution, Many thanks @luk2302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify my comment:

Iterate over the array and calculate the distance between the array element and the current MKMapView point. If the calculated distance is smaller than a certain bound ('nearby' -> e.g. 5000 meters), then do something with that point, e.g. log it or load more data, etc...

For calculating the distance between two long/lat points look at [GPS coordinates in degrees to calculate distances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994101/gps-coordinates-in-degrees-to-calculate-distances), since they are not 2D points in the conventional sense.

Comment: I was going to search about calculating distance between two points :) Thanks