# Calculate distance between 2 point on maps for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, apple-maps

Is it possible to calculate the distance between 2 close points on iOS using Apple map framework or Google framework?
For example, i want to get the distance between this 2 blu point with the highest accuracy possible.

[image]

Using google maps or apple maps can i get the 2 coordinate with a lot of digit? how can i calculate the distance in centimeters or millimeters?

Comment: Yes you get accurate enough data, then use https://stackoverflow.com/a/7175724/1971013

Comment: using CLLocationDistance does it approximates or give me the real distance in meters: it will return for example 30.21m or 30.00m ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GPS coordinates in degrees to calculate distances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994101/gps-coordinates-in-degrees-to-calculate-distances)

Comment: Given that specialized equipment is generally needed to record the location of a point to mm accuracy, it is unlikely that measuring the distance between these two locations with mm precision will result in a measurement accurate to the mm - unless of course they were surveyed points with a known datum.

Comment: @AndrewReid Thanks for your answer. That point will be selected in map (like google maps when you touch for a while the screen). I don't need a GPS that provide me an accurate localization.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this -

```
let coordinate0 = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 5.0)
let coordinate1 = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 3.0)
let distanceInMeters = coordinate0.distance(from: coordinate1)
```

Comment: okey  thank you, i thought that this function would give me only the distance in meters with approximation (ex: 12.32 m -> 12.00 m ). I tried it and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad it worked! If it helps you then please accept the answer:)

Comment: @Miti What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you'll get accurate enough position information.  `CLLocation` has a [`distance(from: CLLocation)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423689-distance) function that does the trick and gives accurate results also for short distances.